# Can't change desktop wallpaper in Windows 7 Starter?

Tags: windows-7

I have some problems about desktop wallpaper.first of all,I have used HP netbook with Windows 7 Starter.I have try to change the background image but I cant find the personalize.

So I search on the internet and download some app for change the desktop background.but the problem is every time I try to change it my desktop background turn black.

Can anyone help me to solve my problem??

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the background in Windows 7 Starter edition. It also looks like there are various things Microsoft have done to stop people getting round this.

You can't replace the file with one of the same name (img9.jpg):

> Microsoft was cute enough to embed code within shell32.dll that check if the seal has been tampered.

[Source](http://www.withinwindows.com/2009/03/31/correction-starter-wallpaper-more-secure-than-i-thought/)

Comment: never used Windows7 before, but... what the hell MS is doing nowadays?

Comment: @Michael - I've no idea, but the **Starter** edition is meant to have severely limited functionality. Either so it runs on netbooks or to force you to upgrade to Home or Professional ;)

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to `C:\windows\web\wallpapers`
2. In a  wallpaper folder, you will find a windows folder.
3. Copy a folder Windows from wallpapers folder to web folder.
4. Rename the web folder
5. go to `C:\windows\`
6. Make one folder name Web
7. Again, in a folder `C:\windows\web\` (make a folder name wallpapers)
8. Go to `C:\windows\web\wallpapers\`(copy any picture, rename it img01.jpg)
9. It will replace with the old wallpapers.
10. Restart your computer.